# SUM function on multiple columns in Lithium ORM

Tags: orm, lithium

I want something like this:

```php
    $res = Model::find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'SUM(col1)' => array(
                'alias' => 'col1_total',
                ),
            'SUM(col2)' => array(
                'alias' => 'col2_total',
                )
            )
        );
```

expected generated SQL:

```sql
    SELECT SUM(col1) AS col1_total, SUM(col2) AS col2_total 
    FROM `tbl` AS `Model` WHERE 1;
```

I tried many ways.
is this possible?

---

a working example for a single col:

```php
        $res = Model::find('all', array(
            'fields' => 'SUM(col1)'
            )
        );
```

Comment: It looks like your nesting is wrong: `SUM(col1)` and `SUM(col2)` should be on the same level.

Comment: @NateAbele sorry, edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool!
working example:

```php
    $res = Model::find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'SUM(col1) AS col1_total',
            'SUM(col2) AS col2_total'
            )
        );
```